# How can I make a custom carrierwave post processor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I need to do some post processing on a file upload that isn't images - in paperclip I can have a custom post processor, but I can't find any way to do this in carrierwave.

Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.7 and CarrierWave 0.6.2.

Answer (score 8):

The OP's question was how to process files which are not images.

Please have a look at this source file on GitHub: 
[carrierwave/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/c2ee2e89d3aa447c6b81186be6d627202d33a97f/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb)  and check the comments.

You'll have create your own CarrierWave uploader sub-class and mount it in your model like this:

```
  def MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

    # this is where the uploaded file will be available in your model,
    # as a `MyUploader` instance:
    #
    mount_uploader :uploaded_file, MyUploader

    ... 
  end
```

Please note that it's mounted on the ActiveRecord attribute `:uploaded_file`.
This means when you access `:uploaded_file` from your model, you will get an instance of your CarrierWave uploader for the particular file which was uploaded.

You can simply define your processing inside your uploader as follows:

```
  class MyUploader < CarrierWave:Uploader::Base
    process :my_custom_processing => [param1,param2,param3]

    def my_custom_processing(param1,param2,param3)
      ...
      # e.g. you could call a method which is defined elsewhere,
      # which operates on a file:
      my_nifty_file_processor( self.uploaded_file ) 
      #
      # or you could just do this directly:
      uploaded_data = self.uploaded_file.read
      ...
    end
  end
```

Inside `my_nifty_file_processor`, you would simply call `read` on the object that gets passed in to read the file.

CarrierWave lets you call `read` on any Uploader instance (= any instance of an uploaded file) and it will read that file.

**One more Tip:**

Sometimes you need to access the ActiveRecord model within your uploader, for which the file was uploaded.

Simply access it inside your uploader code like this:

```
      self.model
```

This lets you store additional information about the uploaded file, such as format, directly in your AR model.

Comment: Thank you, I found your explanation more relevant that the current top one.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post on how to create custom post-processor to create thumbnails of videos, maybe you will find it useful.

https://prograils.com/posts/video-encoding-processor-for-carrierwave/

Comment: This url is no longer available :(

Comment: True, I have moved it here: http://blog.prograils.com/post/46154701464/video-encoding-processor-for-carrierwave

Comment: you do not answer the OP's question - he specifically asks about files which are NOT images!