# How to implement attachment versioning for files with same names? RoR 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave, rails-activestorage

Project based on RoR 5.2. For attachments uploading I use Carrierwave gem and AWS S3 bucket as storage.

I need to implement versioning for uploaded files with same names.

I mean that file with the same name should not be replaced when I will upload a new one.
For example: model User has a mounted uploader for documents. If I will upload file with name «doc.docx» and after I will upload one else file for the same model object and with the same name, old file will be replaced with new one.

I have already investigated that I can generate token or add timestamp to get unique filename, but I need that if I will upload the new file with same name (for example 'doc.docx') for the same object, it shoild be renamed to 'doc(1).docx' or 'doc_1.docx'. And the new one will be renamed to 'doc(2).docx' or 'doc_2.docx', etc.

Versioning in the AWS panel for this bucket has already enabled.

Is there any way to achieve this? I'm ready to change from Carrierwave to Active Storage. But I have not found at least one case for this.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some ideas about renaming. At first, we can split your problem:

1. Problem with file renaming
2. Problem with file versioning

I solved my problem with renaming with similar code (Carrierwave + video processing). Here I created thumbnail version for an uploaded video, with a specific name (write your custom function instead of `png_name`, you can check a number of previously uploaded files and etc):

```
# Create different versions of your uploaded files:
# ffmpegthumbnailer
version :thumb do
  process thumbnail: [{ format: 'png', size: 360, logger: Rails.logger }]
  def full_filename for_file
    png_name for_file, version_name
  end
end

version :preview do
  process thumbnail: [{ format: 'png', size: 600, logger: Rails.logger }]
  def full_filename for_file
    png_name for_file, version_name
  end
end

def png_name(for_file, version_name)
  %Q{#{version_name}_#{for_file.chomp(File.extname(for_file))}.png}
end
```

And you can solve the problem with versioning by creating proxy-model. For instance, you have `User` model, than you create an association called `Document`. You can mount your uploader to the Document model, and use code above for the renaming.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :documents, dependent: :destroy

  def last_document
    documents.last
  end
end

class Document < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :file, DocumentUploader
  validates_integrity_of :file
end
```

Comment: By the way, you can add your custom Carrierwave post-processor for your uploader https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852605/how-can-i-make-a-custom-carrierwave-post-processor